# jquery navigate link with enter key

Tags: jquery

I want the user to go to the link in the "a href" when they hit the enter key.  How do I do that?
I've searched all over and most suggestions are to use the following which doesn't work.  Do you have any other suggestion that I can try?  Thanks for your help.

```
$("a.uniq_red").triger("click");  // doesn't work
$("a.uniq_red").click();  // doesn't work
$("#search-results a").click(); // doesn't work
```

Here is my code so far:

```
   var i=0;
    $('#search').keypress(function(e){

    if (e.which == 13) {
        //$("a.uniq_red").triger(confirm('test'));  //THIS WORKS!!!!

        $("a.uniq_red").simulate('click');  // THIS DOES NOT WORK 
    }
    if (e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40) {
        $('p.key-notification').fadeOut('slow');
    }
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
    arrow = {left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 }
    switch (keyCode) {
        case arrow.down:
            // do something down
            // confirm("test");
            $("#search-results a").eq(i).addClass('uniq_red');
            $("#search-results a").eq(i-1).removeClass('uniq_red');

            i+=1;
        break;
        case arrow.up:
            // do something up
            $("#search-results a").eq(i-2).addClass('uniq_red');
            $("#search-results a").eq(i-1).removeClass('uniq_red');
            i-=1;
        break;
    }
   });
```

I followed a new suggestion and it worked.  But I had to hit enter key twice for the code to navigate to the a href link.

```
$("a.uniq_red").focus();  //This work, but I had to hit enter twice.
$("a.uniq_red").focus().click();  //Essentially, same outcome.
$("a.uniq_red").click().focus();  // also, same outcome.
```

Comment: Instead of trying to simulate a click on a link, why not simply do something like `window.location = 'http://www.example.com'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, what you want to use is:

`window.location = $('a.uniq_red').attr('href');`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to focus it, and it will work like a charm. When the user will press enter, he will click on the link having the `uniq_red` id.

```
$("a.uniq_red").focus();
```

Comment: I tried that and IT WORKED!  Yeah!!!!!  But the first enter key focus it and then I have to press enter key again for the code to navigate to the link.  Is there something to make it go once?  By the way, $("a.uniq_red").focus("click") doesn't work.  I'll edit and add feedback of what else I had discovered.

Comment: $("a.uniq_red").focus(function() { window.location = $(this).attr('href'); }); ought to do the trick. Then again, why bother focusing if you'll be navigating away?

Comment: Yup' ! I suggest you to focus only if it is a page where the user is not supposed to click away immediately.
However, indeed, if he clicks away, the focus will be lost.
On such case, you can do this :) =>
`setTimeout(function() { $("a.uniq_red").focus(); }, 0);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  On and off , it took me 2 weeks working on this issue of navigating away.  I really appreciate your help.